# How to get WAV file out of blob in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, audio, sox

I have a front-end in ReactJS where I am using MediaRecorder to record the voice from microphone and storing that into an audio blob with mime type "audio/mp3".
I am then uploading that blob to IBM cloud object storage. My usecase is I want to MIX some of my audios and concatenate some audios and for this I am using SOX in NodeJS. So, I have used cosHandler in Node where I am downloading the objects which I have stored earlier i.e blobs.
Mine getCosObject function looks something like below:

```
const getCosObject = async(key, itemName) => {
  var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(`${'/tmp/'}${itemName}`);
  console.log(`Retrieving audio from bucket: ${bucketName}, key: ${key}`);
  return cos.getObject({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
  }).promise()
    .then(async(data) => {
      if (data !== null) {
        wstream.write(data.Body);
        console.log('Audio FILE Downloaded from COS::', itemName);
        return;
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(`ERROR: ${e.code} - ${e.message} - ${itemName}\n`);
      return;
    });
};
```

But when I use SOX over those files this is what error I get:

```
Error from the SOX command: FAIL formats: can't open input file `/tmp/processedAnswer1Me.wav': WAVE: RIFF header not found
```

Note: When I convert my blob to WAV in my ReactJS using decodeAudioData function of AudioContext and the audioBufferToWav function, then my SOX command runs successfully in NODE. 
Why I do not want to implement this is because the size of WAV file after this is having exceptionally large size than blob.

Using SOXI for my error generated blob is below:

```
Input File     : '/tmp/PreQNADiscussion.wav'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 32000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:03.34 = 107008 samples ~ 250.8 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 2.21M
Bit Rate       : 5.28M
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)
```

And when I use SOXI for WAV converted audio i.e which I don't want to implement

```
Input File     : '/tmp/QNA1tts.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:03.95 = 174375 samples = 296.556 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 349k
Bit Rate       : 706k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Any help?